# Python broke when installing 3.x

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I had my mac osx working fine with `python 2.7.10`, and I've installed `python3` via `brew install python3`.

on my `bash_profile` I then create an `alias python=python3`.

but when I

`>>python3`

I got:

`Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 2.x but you are running Python 3.x!
PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:"
You should unset PYTHONPATH to fix this.`

then I ran `brew uninstall python3`, but things did not come to previous configuration, and I couldn't run neither `python` versions anymore.

`>>python` now gives me:

`-bash: python3: command not found`

I tried then to `brew link python3`, since it appeared to be there, but to no avail.

now, If I `which python`, I get:

`/usr/local/bin/python`.

**how do I fix this mess, minding that I want to keep both 2.7 and 3.5?**

*ps. my bash_profile now*:

```
export PATH=“/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:~/bin:./bin:$PATH"
"export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Comment: best why to fix things is to use `virtual environments` as this will force the python version if you have multiple python installations.

Comment: I don't know anything about OSX, but is their something similar to windows enviorment variables? Just manually set the PYTHONPATH enviorment variable.

Comment: Did my answer work? What happened?

Comment: the linked answer is too broad...I am still trying to figure out how to set the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable manually to point to the correct python installation. If you want both, set it to both (separated with a `;` semicolon) and just specify in the cmd `python2` or `python3` depending on which you want to open.

This explains how to access the enviorment variables on OSX:

[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Sorry, I'd provide more detail but I only run Linux and Windows on my home machines so I don't know much about OSX.

edit: actually, you may need to seperate different locations with a `,` comma rather then semicolon. Don't know, look at the existing ones to see how it is.

Comment: the thing is: `3.5` installed via `homebrew` is not inside `Python.framework`, only `2.7`, yet brew says that it is already installed.

Comment: somehow it worked when I  did  `unset PYTHONPATH`. now it fires `python 3.5`

Comment: @data_garden is that what you wanted? If so, accept please! Otherwise, just set it to what you want.